# Article vs amsart

Tags: article, amsart

I am a UG mathematics student who uses latex for making short notes and am nowadays learning latex. Which document class should I prefer working on, the article class or the amsart??

Comment: I would recommend to use the standard article class. I expect a better support from the community and a better chance to find solved problems in the internet.

Comment: In addition, if you buy a recent Latex book, then I expect that the article class will be covered (ams probably not). I do recommend to read a recent latex book to get a structured introduction in contrast to Google all the time.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, I am using the 2016 edition of _More math into latex_ by George Gratzer and most of the commands it says work in both article and amsart document class, rest work only in amsart document class. That is why I am asking which one is better to be practiced, more comfortable to use, shows more elegant output, and more useful in later life.

Comment: Ok. I would still use the article class according to my other comments

Comment: If you are planning to submit articles to a U.S. "academic" math journal, then `amsart` may be the better option, although the record of fixing bugs is less than admirable.  `amsart` natively incorporates `amsmath` and `amsthm`, and "marks up" the top matter (bibliographic info) differently from `article` so that it is easily extracted to send to indexing agencies.  The output is styled differently; which appearance you prefer is a matter of personal taste.  The markup of the body is essentially identical so switching between the two classes should be relatively painless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choice of the class depends on your preference. Even some people prefer article. there are some macro that I need to change before I can use this class. The same time some journals prefer specific classes designed to formats of these journals. For instance, Physics Review request to submit papers using revtex class which design paper in two column format and has special macro for extra long formula. AMS Bulletin require amsart class; and even more, they require to use newcommand instead of def because they have special publishing procedure