# paracol creates empty lines

Tags: paracol

I tried to use package paracol because I want to put similar theorems near one another, so reader can compare them. But I put attention that original text grow up from 290 to 320. Looking what happens I find small example

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep3pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
 \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{framedPage}[1][\hsize]
{\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{shadedPage}[1][\hsize]
{
\def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed{ \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\begin{paracol}{2}
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left 

It remains to  prove that
the kernel of inefficiency consists only of identity.
Identity transformation
satisfies to equation
\[
v^i=v^ja_i^j
\]
Choosing values of coordinates as
$v^i=\delta^i_k$
where we selected $k$ we get
\begin{equation}
\label{identity col}
\delta^i_k=\delta^j_ka^i_j
\end{equation}
From \eqref{identity col} it follows
\[
\delta^i_k=a^i_k
\]
Since $k$ is arbitrary, we get the conclusion $a=\delta$.
\switchcolumn%
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left 
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left 

It remains to  prove that
the kernel of inefficiency consists only of identity.
Identity transformation
satisfies to equation
\[
v_i=v_ja^j_i
\]
Choosing values of coordinates as
$v_i=\delta^k_i$
where we selected $k$ we get
\begin{equation}
\label{identity row}
\delta^k_i=\delta^k_ja^j_i
\end{equation}
From \eqref{identity row} it follows
\[
\delta^k_i=a^k_i
\]
Since $k$ is arbitrary, we get the conclusion $a=\delta$.
\end{paracol}


\end{document}
```

You can see that on second page there few empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

There are exactly equal if you use the same content for both columns.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep3pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
 \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{framedPage}[1][\hsize]
{\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{shadedPage}[1][\hsize]
{
\def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed{ \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\begin{paracol}{2}
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
According to the theorem the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear GL-representation.
According to the theorem the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left It remains to  prove that
the kernel of inefficiency consists only of identity.
Identity transformation satisfies to equation
\[v^i=v^ja_i^j\]
Choosing values of coordinates as
$v^i=\delta^i_k$
where we selected $k$ we get
\begin{equation}
\label{identity col}
\delta^i_k=\delta^j_ka^i_j
\end{equation}
From \eqref{identity col} it follows
\[\delta^i_k=a^i_k\]
Since $k$ is arbitrary, we get the conclusion $a=\delta$.

\switchcolumn%
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
According to the theorem the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear GL-representation.
According to the theorem the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left It remains to  prove that
the kernel of inefficiency consists only of identity.
Identity transformation satisfies to equation
\[v^i=v^ja_i^j\]
Choosing values of coordinates as
$v^i=\delta^i_k$
where we selected $k$ we get
\begin{equation}
\label{identity col}
\delta^i_k=\delta^j_ka^i_j
\end{equation}
From \eqref{identity col} it follows
\[\delta^i_k=a^i_k\]
Since $k$ is arbitrary, we get the conclusion $a=\delta$.
\end{paracol}
```

In order not to be confused with the text of two similar theorems one after the other, I suggest defining new commands, for example `\firsttheorem`   and   `\secondtheorem` each one holding the content of its theorem.

Then use

```
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \firsttheorem 
\switchcolumn%
  \secondtheorem
\end{paracol}
```

As in this code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep3pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{framedPage}[1][\hsize]
{\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{shadedPage}[1][\hsize]
{
\def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed{ \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\newcommand{\firsttheorem}{% first theorem
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
According to the theorem the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear GL-representation.
According to the theorem the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left It remains to  prove that
the kernel of inefficiency consists only of identity.
Identity transformation satisfies to equation
\[v^i=v^ja_i^j\]
Choosing values of coordinates as
$v^i=\delta^i_k$
where we selected $k$ we get
\begin{equation}
\label{identity col}
\delta^i_k=\delta^j_ka^i_j
\end{equation}
From \eqref{identity col} it follows
\[\delta^i_k=a^i_k\]
    Since $k$ is arbitrary, we get the conclusion $a=\delta$.       
    }


\newcommand{\secondtheorem}{% a similar theorem
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
According to the theorem the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear GL-representation.
According to the theorem the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left It remains to  prove that
the kernel of inefficiency consists only of identity.
Identity transformation satisfies to equation
\[v^i=v^ja_i^j\]
Choosing values of coordinates as
$v^i=\delta^i_k$
where we selected $k$ we get
\begin{equation}
\label{identity col}
\delta^i_k=\delta^j_ka^i_j
\end{equation}
From \eqref{identity col} it follows
\[\delta^i_k=a^i_k\]
Since $k$ is arbitrary, we get the conclusion $a=\delta$.       
}


\begin{paracol}{2}
\firsttheorem   
\switchcolumn%
\secondtheorem
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

The gap in the second page is originated by the combination of `paracol` and `amsart`.

The gap disappears using a standard class as `article` and add `\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}` to make the `amslatex` commands available.

See also [Article vs amsart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541113/article-vs-amsart)

[image: d]

Comment: The theorem is like it is. I cannot put Leibnitz theorem instead of Pifagor theorem. I also do not like this empty space in the beginning of the second page.

Comment: @Aleks Kleyn Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes. This works better and may be will give some key to find answer. Thank you